# IronPdf IronSoftwareDeploymentException in Azure Wep App

Tags: c#, .net, azure-web-app-service, ironpdf

I am getting below exception after deploying HTML to PDF functionality in Azure Web App(.net Framework 4.8).Same is working fine in local .

```
IronSoftware.Exceptions.IronSoftwareDeploymentException: Error while deploying IronPdf Chrome renderer: 'Unable to locate 'IronInterop' in C:\home\site\wwwroot\, C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin, C:\local\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\26df21a6\54e3e732\assembly\dl3\9559295f\001eed5d_d423d901, C:\home\site\wwwroot, Embedded resource (IronPdf, Version=2023.1.0.11416, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94e1c31412563c75: IronPdf) to path 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\runtimes\win-x64\native', Embedded resource (IronPdf, Version=2023.1.0.11416, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94e1c31412563c75: IronPdf) to path 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\runtimes\win.10-x64\native', Embedded resource (IronPdf, Version=2023.1.0.11416, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94e1c31412563c75: IronPdf) to path 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\' nor in an embedded resource'. To learn more about making an engineering support request please visit: <a href=https://ironpdf.com/troubleshooting/engineering-request-pdf/>.
To learn how to solve this issue please read https://iron.helpscoutdocs.com/article/194-azure-functions-deployment2 
[Issue Code IRONPDF-CHROME-DEPLOYMENT-ERROR-AMZN] ---> IronSoftware.Exceptions.IronSoftwareDeploymentException: 
Unable to locate 'IronInterop' in C:\home\site\wwwroot\, C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin, C:\local\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\26df21a6\54e3e732\assembly\dl3\9559295f\001eed5d_d423d901,
 C:\home\site\wwwroot, Embedded resource (IronPdf, Version=2023.1.0.11416, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94e1c31412563c75: IronPdf) to path 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\runtimes\win-x64\native', 
 Embedded resource (IronPdf, Version=2023.1.0.11416, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94e1c31412563c75: IronPdf) 
 to path 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\runtimes\win.10-x64\native', Embedded resource (IronPdf, Version=2023.1.0.11416, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94e1c31412563c75: IronPdf) 
 to path 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\' nor in an embedded resourceat IronSoftware.Deployment.SmartDeploymentBase.ThrowRelevantException(List`1 exceptions)at
 IronSoftware.Deployment.SmartDeploymentBase.Deploy(Boolean download)at IronSoftware.Deployment.DeploymentEngine.Deploy[T](String custom_dir, Boolean download)--- 
 End of inner exception stack trace
```

I have already added dependent nuget IronPdf.Native.Chrome.Windows as suggested.
Below is the code :

```
var renderer = new ChromePdfRenderer();
 renderer.RenderingOptions.RenderDelay = Convert.ToInt32(SiteSettingsPage.Settings.PDFRenderDelay);
                renderer.RenderingOptions.MarginTop = 12;
                renderer.RenderingOptions.MarginBottom = 12;
                renderer.RenderingOptions.MarginLeft = 0;
                renderer.RenderingOptions.MarginRight = 0;
                renderer.RenderingOptions.PaperOrientation = 
                IronPdf.Rendering.PdfPaperOrientation.Portrait;
                renderer.RenderingOptions.PaperSize = IronPdf.Rendering.PdfPaperSize.A4;
 var pdf = renderer.RenderUrlAsPdf(htmlFileUrl).BinaryData;
```

Comment: Does you application run on build machine in both Debug and Release folders?  When you deploy it is using the Release folder on build machine.  You may be running successfully with debug on build machine.  Check the dates in the bin folder of project and see if the Debug and Release executable are current.

Comment: Make sure your packages are updated. Use the latest versions.

Comment: Are you deploying to Azure `Windows` or `Linux` App Service ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the above requirement I have reproduced from my end I tried your code it works fine in local but where as deployed in webapp it was showing error.

Thanks  @jdweng for your suggestions in the comments. Below is the code which I tried to reproduce.

```
        var renderer = new ChromePdfRenderer();
        var pdf = renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf(File.ReadAllText(htmlFilePath));
        pdf.SaveAs(pdfFilePath);

        Console.WriteLine($"PDF saved to {pdfFilePath}");
        Console.WriteLine("Conversion complete!");

        var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile("azureauth.properties");
        var azure = Azure.Configure().WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic).Authenticate(credentials).WithDefaultSubscription();
        var webApp = azure.WebApps.GetById("resource-group-name", "webapp-name");

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(pdfFilePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            webApp.Inner.WebApps.CreateOrUpdateSiteBlobSource("wwwroot", "pdf-file-name.pdf", fileStream);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"PDF uploaded to {webApp.DefaultHostName}/pdf-file-name.pdf");
    }
}
```

- In the above code `SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile` method to read your Azure credentials from a file called "azureauth.properties" that should be located in the same directory as your program file.
- `azure.WebApps.GetById` method retrieves an instance of your web app using the resource group and web app names.
- `FileStream` object to read the contents of the PDF file, and then use the `webApp.Inner.WebApps.CreateOrUpdateSiteBlobSource` method to create or update a blob in the web app's root directory

[image]

- I have created a webapp in portal and deployed from visual studio code editor successfully.

[image]

- I am able to see the converted .html to .pdf in local Aswell as in www.root directory.

[image]

[image]